# Dynamically add an unknown number of button to UI in Qt in C++

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm trying to inset QPushButton in a grid layout which is pretty easy  but I won't know the number in advance.

Here is what I have:

testapp.cpp

```
#include "testapp.h"

testApp::testApp(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
    : QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            QPushButton* panelButton = new QPushButton();
            panelButton->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
            ui.PanelButtonGridLayout->addWidget(panelButton,i,j);
        }
    }
}

testApp::~testApp()
{

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>

#include "testapp.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    testApp w;
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

So I know that this won't work because the object is going to be deleted at the end of the current loop.

I thought about creating a QList (for example) of QPushButton in the main and pass it to the testapp class but I'm not sure it's a good solution. there might be way better ways.

EDIT:
For some reasons, it wasn't compiling. It now is. I hate when that arrives.

Comment: "So I know that this won't work because the object is going to be deleted at the end of the current loop". Hmm, what object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, no, the object will not be deleted at the end of the loop, as you're allocating it on the heap, and not on the stack:

```
 QPushButton* panelButton = new QPushButton();
```

In this case, buttons will be destroyed automatically when their parent (`ui.PanelButtonGridLayout`) is destroyed.

As the comments below state, the parent of the object will be set internally by `addWidget` method.

From the [documentation](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qlayout.html#addItem):

> Note: The ownership of item is transferred to the layout, and it's the layout's responsibility to delete it.

Comment: addWidget should take care of that (BTW, I'm not the downvoter...)

Comment: No, there's no need here. The `addWidget` call transfer the ownership.